# One click switch between Windows and MacOS

Tags: macos, windows

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to quickly switch between my Mac and Windows machine. Both are sitting on my desktop and it is a pain to change the keyboard, mouse and display cables each time.

I have both computers plugged into the same monitor but I still need to change the source on the display.

Is it possible to solve this reliably somehow?

Comment: You could use Microsoft Remote Desktop to access the Windows machine from the Mac. You can switch between the Mac and Windows desktops by using the control+arrow keys.  Microsoft Remote Desktop is free and can be downloaded from the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [KVM [keyboard, video & mouse] switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch)
Which type would depend on your choices of input & output on both your machines.